# Learning words from the servants of Rebbi

Tags: words, talmud-gemara, sources-mekorot

Where is the gemarah that discusses how the sages didn't know the meaning of certain words until their heard the servants of Rebbi Yehuda HaNasi using those words in everyday conversation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are referring to the Gemara on [Megillah 18a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=18&format=pdf), which is paralleled on [Rosh HaShana 26b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=26b&format=pdf)?